# An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project"

Tags: maven

When i update my maven project while at that time, i'm getting following error.
For your reference i have attached the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes restarting eclipse helps. If not, in Eclipse top tab, try Project->Clean...

try to run mvn eclipse:clean

Disable and then enable maven nature (right click->Maven->Disable Maven Nature)