# Internal error occurred in Eclipse Luna during Maven Project Update

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When i update the maven project at that time, i'm getting following error. Screen shot for reference. I can't able get a proper solution for this problem, any one suggest solution for this problem

[image]

Comment: Well there's a "Details" button, what does it show?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: Details buttons shows:An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject

Comment: possible duplicate of [An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155887/an-internal-error-occurred-during-updating-maven-project)

Comment: i think this may be duplicate, in my organization the following link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155887/an-internal-error-occurred-during-updating-maven-project) was blocked by the firewall, can you please suggest any other solution.